# Dynamic amount of Views should each bind to corresponding ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac, mvvm-light

**The situation:** The idea is, to have a config.xml, where Column-Count and Row-Count can be defined, as well as some information on what should be displayed for each cell (i.e. an image path, a html path, an id for a workflow). This config do I read and save in a `Config`-class:

```
public class Config
{
    public int RowCount;
    public int ColumnCount;
    public List<PictureConfig> PictureConfigs;
    public List<HtmlConfig> HtmlConfigs;
    public List<WorkflowConfig> WorkflowConfigs;
}
```

For this purpose I created a view for each type of cell content => `ImageView`, `HtmlView`, `WorkflowView` and of course respectively the corresponding ViewModels, which should deliver the stuff to display for the given path or id.

I am using WPF, MVVM Light with Autofac and have a `ViewModelLocator.`

**The problem:** As seen in my `Config`-class, there can be multiple Views of the same type (each time with a different info on what to display). Now in MVVM Light, the view-first idea is given, but ..

**..how can a dynamically amount of views each bind to the correct ViewModel and how to I create the right amount of ViewModels (that hold each another info, i.e. picture path) in the first place?**

**My thoughts:** When I know from the config, that 3 Cells with picture-content exist and just create 3 instances of `PictureViewModel`, how do I then create a View 3 times as well? Or the other way around, if I create 3 Views, and give them each a new ViewModel, those ViewModels don't know which information to display...

I have been puzzling for a couple of days now, but could not find a clean way.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Lets say your ViewModel has some collection with models - (public List<MyModel> Models { get; set; }) and you want to display a view for each one of them. The only thing you have to do is to decide in what form you want to present the models - a ListView provides means to select each one, a DataGrid provides means to add rows, an ItemsControl will just stack them. Declare one of those in your XAML and bind its ItemsSource. Now set its ItemTemplate, which would tell the control how to idisplay each view and you are done. Just remember that you can bind only to a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with was, that at the moment of creating new views (i.e. adding `new ImageView` to the children of a `Grid`), I pass the Id for the relative `PictureConfig`. So the view can then tell the Id its `ViewModel`, which will find the correct `PictureConfig` in the PictureConfigs-List by the Id.